# How to know Fragment id for the fragment(s) provided by the tabbed activity template

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used the tabbed activity template provided by android studio but i can't happen to find the id for the different fragments used. the template had only one .xml and .java for all three fragments. I made a few changes and made three separate .xml and .java for the three fragments. But I can't figure out how to set the id for the different fragments either from .xml or in .java and without the id I can't perform inter fragment communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now for retrieving a fragment

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(mViewPager.getId(), mViewPager.getCurrentItem()));


public static String getFragmentTag(int viewId, long id) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + id;
}
```

Comment: MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity and the Fragment classes extend Fragmen. They can't implement an abstract class. Interface is needed. And also, in which part of the code do i set the id for the fragments?

Comment: You will find a `SectionPagerAdapter` in your `MainActivity class` extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`. If you take a look into a `instantiateItem` method of `FragmentPagerAdapter` `mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                    makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));` here during fragment initiation a tag has been added with the fragment. So for retrieving  the fragment you just need to call a `Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) ;`

Comment: If you need to add a custom tag to a fragment for later retrieve you need to create a new class extending FragmentPagerAdapter.