# Call method from Fragment in unselected tab

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an application with tabs. I use `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`. In each tab I have a `Fragment`. When the tab is unselected I want to call a method from the fragment in that tab.

If I want to call method on selected fragment i will do:

```java
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                String tag = "android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" +  viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
                ((MyFragment) f).someMethod();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

based on the [How to know Fragment id for the fragment(s) provided by the tabbed activity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555081/how-to-know-fragment-id-for-the-fragments-provided-by-the-tabbed-activity-temp)

But the problem is, that I don't know how to do it on unselected tab.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try run your code in `onTabUnselected` method, but be aware that this fragment may be destroyed in a next step.

```
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // tag for tab position
            String tag = "android:switcher:" + viewPager.getId() + ":" +  tab.getPosition();
            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if(f instanceof MyFragment) {
                ((MyFragment) f).someMethodWhenUnselecting();
            }
        }
```

also remember that `ViewPager` keeps in memory only current and one `Fragment` to the left and one to the right of current. so if you moving from e.g. `5` position to `4` then position `3` and below aren't existing

pozdrowienia

Comment: Dziękuje bardzo :)